# Hybrid argument for quantum states

Tags: quantum-cryptography, indistinguishability

The usual hybrid argument tells us that if two efficiently sampled ensembles are computationally indistinguishable based on a single sample, then, computational indistinguishability holds even for polynomially-many independent samples.

My question is based on the fact of a quantum state induces a probability distribution, and is as follows:

Can the hybrid argument be extended to the fact that if two quantum states $\rho_0,\rho_1$ are computationally indistinguishable to all QPT adversaries $\mathcal{A}$, then by giving any adversary $\mathcal{A}$ polynomially-many copies of the quantum states $\rho_0^{\otimes p(\lambda)}, \rho_1^{\otimes p(\lambda)}$, then the distributions of the outputs of $\mathcal{A}$ are still indistinguishable? (I.e., $\rho_0^{\otimes p(\lambda)}, \rho_1^{\otimes p(\lambda)}$ are computational indistinguishable?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming $\mathcal{A}$ can by itself generate copies of $\rho_0$ and $\rho_1$, then yes this is the case.

\begin{align*}
  &\| \mathcal{A}(\rho_0^{\otimes p}) -  \mathcal{A}(\rho_0^{\otimes p})\| \\
  &\leq \sum_i \| \mathcal{A}(\rho_0^{\otimes (p-i)}\otimes \rho_1^{\otimes i}) -  \mathcal{A}(\rho_0^{\otimes (p-i-1)}\otimes \rho_1^{\otimes i+1}) \|\\
  &\leq  \sum_i \| \mathcal{A}_i(\rho_1) -  \mathcal{A}_i(\rho_0)\|\\
\end{align*}
where $\mathcal{A}_i$ prepares $p-i-1$ copies of $\rho_0$ and $i$ copies of $\rho_1$ and on input $\rho$ outputs $\mathcal{A}(\rho_0^{\otimes (p-i-1)}\otimes \rho \otimes \rho_1^{\otimes i})$.

If $\mathcal{A}$ cannot construct copies of $\rho_0$ or $\rho_1$ by itself, then you need to assume *nonuniform* indistinguishability of $\rho_0$ and $\rho_1$, so that the state $\rho_0^{\otimes (p-i-1)}\otimes\rho_1^{\otimes i}$ can be given as quantum advice to $\mathcal{A}_i$.